# How predictable is NEWSEQUENTIALID?

Tags: sql, sql-server, primary-key, guid, newsequentialid

According to [Microsoft's documentation on `NEWSEQUENTIALID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189786.aspx), the output of NEWSEQUENTIALID is predictable. But how predictable is predictable? Say I have a GUID that was generated by `NEWSEQUENTIALID`, how hard would it be to:

- Calculate the next value?
- Calculate the previous value?
- Calculate the first value?
- Calculate the first value, even without knowing any GUID's at all?
- Calculate the amount of rows? E.g. when using integers, `/order?id=842` tells me that there are 842 orders in the application.

Below is some background information about what I am doing and what the various tradeoffs are.

One of the *security* benefits of using GUID's over integers as primary keys is that GUID's are hard to guess. E.g. say a hacker sees a URL like `/user?id=845` he might try to access `/user?id=0`, since it is probable that the first user in the database is an administrative user. Moreover, a hacker can iterate over `/user?id=0..1..2` to quickly gather all users.

Similarly, a *privacy* downside of integers is that they leak information. `/order?id=482` tells me that the web shop has had 482 orders since its implementation.

Unfortunately, using GUID's as primary keys has well-known *performance* downsides. To this end, SQL Server introduced the `NEWSEQUENTIALID` function. In this question, I would like to learn how predictable the output of `NEWSEQUENTIALID` is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The underlying OS function is [`UuidCreateSequential`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379322%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The value is derived from one of your network cards MAC address and a [per-os-boot incremental value](http://ayende.com/blog/4628/implementing-createsequentialuuid). See [RFC4122](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt). SQL Server does some [byte-shuffling](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dbrowne/archive/2012/07/03/how-to-generate-sequential-guids-for-sql-server-in-net.aspx) to make the result sort properly. So the value is highly predictable, in a sense. Specifically, if you know a value you can immediately predict a range of similar value.

However one cannot predict the equivalent of `id=0`, nor can it predict that `52DE358F-45F1-E311-93EA-00269E58F20D` means the store sold at least 482 items.

The only 'approved' random generation is [`CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627408.aspx) (which wraps [`CryptGenRandom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379942%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) but that is obviously a horrible key candidate.

Comment: Excellent and thorough response!

Answer (score 5):

In most cases, the next `newsequentialid` can be predicted by taking the current value and adding one to the first hex pair.

In other words:

> **1E**29E599-45F1-E311-80CA-00155D008B1C

is followed by

> **1F**29E599-45F1-E311-80CA-00155D008B1C

is followed by

> **20**29E599-45F1-E311-80CA-00155D008B1C

Occasionally, the sequence will restart from a new value.

So, it's very predictable

`NewSequentialID` is a wrapper around the windows function [`UuidCreateSequential`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa379322%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I have observed similar behavior in my database. A series of rows seems to follow a pattern but then suddenly jumps to a new value. Can this new value be guessed as well?

Answer (score 2):

• Calculate the next value? Yes

Microsoft says:

If privacy is a concern, do not use this function. It is possible to guess the value of the next generated GUID and, therefore, access data associated with that GUID.

SO it's a possibility to get the next value. I don't find information if it is possible to get the prevoius one.

from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189786.aspx

edit: another few words about NEWSEQUENTIALID and security: http://vadivel.blogspot.com/2007/09/newid-vs-newsequentialid.html

**Edit:**
NewSequentialID contains the server's MAC address (or one of them), therefore knowing a sequential ID gives a potential attacker information that may be useful as part of a security or DoS attack.
from: [Are there any downsides to using NewSequentialID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17932298/are-there-any-downsides-to-using-newsequentialid)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am aware that NEWSEQUENTIALID is predictable. In this question, I would like to find out *how* predictable.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this code:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (
    PK uniqueidentifier DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID(),
    Num int
)
INSERT INTO @tbl(Num) values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5)
select * from @tbl
```

On my machine in this time is result:

```
PK                                      Num
52DE358F-45F1-E311-93EA-00269E58F20D    1
53DE358F-45F1-E311-93EA-00269E58F20D    2
54DE358F-45F1-E311-93EA-00269E58F20D    3
55DE358F-45F1-E311-93EA-00269E58F20D    4
56DE358F-45F1-E311-93EA-00269E58F20D    5
```

You should try it several times in different time/date to interpolate the behaviour.
I tried it run several times and the first part is changing everytime (you see in results: 52...,53...,54...,etc...). I waited some time to check it, and after some time the second part is incremented too. I suppose the incementation continues to the all parts. Basically it look like simple `+=1` incementation transformed into Guid.

**EDIT:**

If you want sequential GUID and you want have control over the values,  you can use [Sequences](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx).

Sample code:

```
select cast(cast(next value for [dbo].[MySequence] as varbinary(max)) as uniqueidentifier)
```

Comment: What's the use then?  Why not just use 1,2,3,4,5?